# How to run QGIS 2.18.15 with GRASS 6.4.3

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

Algorithm wanted by me: v.segment is not working in QGIS 2.18.15 with grass7 https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17850, so I have to use grass6. It was working in my QGIS 2.18.1, but I had to change to 2.18.15 and I don't remember previous settings.

Starting from scratch. I install QGIS and then try to set paths to GRASS 6 from older QGIS in Processing->Options, but this is no working :(

EDIT:
Here is the option window (sorry for polish):
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Options dialogue?

Comment: @AndreJ - See edited post. Generally I try there different combinations, i.e. copying those folders from QGIS Lyon to QGIS 2.18.15 folder, but still no effect.

What is strange, after restart paths sometimes dissapears...

Comment: The blanks in the folder paths might be an issue. As an alternative, you might try the OSGeo4W setup, which installs everything into `C:\OSGEO4W64\`. You can select and install GRASS6 there too. BTW the issues seems to be fixed now, so you could stay with GRASS7 as well, manually editing the py file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I even didn't know that it is so easy fix and I can do it by myself :) Now v.segment in grass 7 works perfectly.